# I've problems with Python global

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, global-variables

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052266/problems-with-global-variables-in-python), but it's not into a class.

My code is this (after removing some ininfluent lines):

```
@Bot.command()
async def Limonate(ctx, secondi, menzione=None):
    global attesa
    global canale
    attesa = float(secondi)
    canale = ctx.channel
```

This is a command, and I need that part to do this:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    attesa = 100
    while (True):
        frase = choice(frasi_ad_effetto)
        await sleep(attesa)
        global canale # Here's the problem
        global menzione
        await canale.send(menzione + ', ' + frase) #
```

So the problem is that, if the `Bot` has just started (and the `command` `Limonate` was never executed), the `canale` variable is empty.

Do you know any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in function `Limonate`, you need to declare `canale` as a global variable before setting it to the value.

```
@Bot.command()
async def Limonate(ctx, secondi, menzione = None):
    global attesa, canale
    attesa = float(secondi)
    canale = ctx.channel
```